# Why am I receiving a "Cast from '[String]' to unrelated type 'String' always fails" error?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I’m trying to display an array of data (stored within a Firestore database field entitled "product") into a UITableViewController. The code I am currently using to try and return the array into my app is below:

```
if userId == user?.uid {               
   let group_array = document["product"] as? Array ?? [""]
    let productName1 = (group_array) as? String
      self.tableViewData =[cellData(opened: false, title: "Item 1", sectionData: [productName1 ?? "No data to display :("])]
   }
```

When I run this, it compiles, however I’m currently getting the following warning message:

> Cast from '[String]' to unrelated type 'String' always fails”

This results in no data being returned, and returning nil for `productName1`, consequently leading to the "No data to display :(" message being shown instead of the data.

Does anyone know which type I would need to assign for the following line to return this data please?

```
let productName1 = (group_array) as? String
```

Comment: `group_array` is a `[String]`, it's an Array of `String`, imagine it as being a list of `String`. How do you transform it into a `String`, ie Like you are expecting a candy, BUT you give an bag of candy. So you'll pick on inside?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `group_array` as an `Array`. Then you try to cast it to a String. You can't cast an Array (even an array of String objects) to a String.

This line:

```
let productName1 = (group_array) as? String
```

Will always fail.

What result are you looking for? The first entry in the array of strings? A string that combines all the elements in the array together?

If you want the first element, use

```
let productName1 = group_array.first as? string ?? ""
```

If you want to combine the items, use something like this:

```
let productNames = (group_array as? [String])?.joined(separator: ", ") ?? ""
```

By the way, your code would be cleaner if you cast your array to an array of Strings, not just a generic Array (Array of Any)

Change:

let group_array = document["product"] as? Array ?? [""]

To:

let group_array = document["product"] as? [String] ?? [""]

Comment: Great thank you - If I wanted to retrieve the second element, would I just use `let productName2 = group_array.second as? string ?? ""`? Manually searching for the first, second, third etc. elements of the array seems very tedious, so I'm wondering if there is a way of automatically retrieving each element of the array and adding to a separate `cellData` section.

Comment: No. There is not property `.second` on Array. There are special-case properties `.first` and `.last` that let you get to the first and last elements in the array (or return nil if the array is empty.

Comment: Array supports integer indexing, as well as looping. Once you makes sure there are enough elements in the array, you can use `group_array[2]` or `for item in group_array` to loop through them.

Comment: Ok, understood. When I use this to display the second element of the array, when there is only 1 element, the app crashes, even though I am using an Optional (with an error message to show if nothing is found once productName2 is unwrapped) ` let productName2 = group_array[2] ?? "No data to display :("` Is there a reason as to why it is crashing instead of showing the "No data to display :(" message?

Comment: Yes, that is expected. `array[index]` is only legal if there are enough elements for `index` to be valid. You need to check the number of elements first before indexing into the array. These are language fundamentals. You should probably do some reading on Swift basics.